# lubuntu (lxde desktop) - is there any device notifier in panel?

Tags: lubuntu, notification, lxde, lxpanel

I have lubuntu 13.04 and I'd like to know if there is any device notifier to show in lxde panel in order to safetely remove safely or manage usb and other device without opening lxde folder manager?

Thanks